# CSS grid doesn't stretch to 100% on smaller screens

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a page layout with two columns: a sidebar and the rest of the page content. Sidebar needs to be 300px width, while the rest of the content needs to fill what's left. I've used CSS grid for this and `grid-template-columns: 300px auto` (and even tried grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr). And it works on bigger screens. But on screens around tablet size, the content doesn't stretch to 100% / doesn't fill what's left. And I'm not sure what's wrong.

Here's my code outline:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px auto;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  background: green;
}

.content {
  height: 100vh;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong and is there a way I could do this differently with CSS grid to avoid this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Is there any other HTML content, or CSS, outside of your container that could affect behaviour? E.g. margins on body.

Comment: @AndyG Yup, a bunch of CSS since I'm making this on WordPress. But I have no clue what could it even be.

Comment: Inspect the page with the browser's developer tools to discover what content is present to the right of the grid.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit late but I think you could try this:

```
.container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 300px minmax(0, 1fr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always make use of `calc` function, by older means of float and setting  width.
This surely works for all kind of device.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: green;
}

.content {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
  height: 100vh;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

the problem is coming from the column width being fixed at `300px`. You can use a media query and assign the `grid-template-columns` to `auto` at a fixed screen width and below. Example is for any screen size of 600px or less, the width goes to auto taking up the entire screen.

CSS

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px auto;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  background: green;
}

.content {
  height: 100vh;
  background: gray;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: auto;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dxefc73o/

Comment: This does not explain what is wrong with the original code.

Comment: The issue is that the width is fixed originally. to resolve this, either set `max-width: 300px` and `width:100%`. Or do the change above